# Ubuntu runner does not expand double star

Tags: node.js, github-actions, yarnpkg

I have the following test command in `package.json`:

```json
    "test": "node --test --enable-source-maps --loader ts-node/esm lib/**/*.test.ts && node --test index.test.js"
```

It runs locally, but on CI it fails:

```
yarn run v1.22.21
$ node --test --enable-source-maps --loader ts-node/esm lib/**/*.test.ts && node --test index.test.js
Could not find '/home/runner/work/assert-raisins/assert-raisins/lib/**/*.test.ts'
```

It looks like `**` isn't being expanded. I tried to insert `shopt -s globstar` just about anywhere, but to no avail.

Full workflow YAML:

```yaml
name: Node.js CI

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "master" ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "master" ]

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: yarn
    - name: Run tests
      run: yarn test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NPM scripts use `sh` from your `PATH` by default](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#script-shell). On some systems (like macOS), this "sh" is actually just `bash` in disguise, but that does not appear to be the case in the Github Action Runner.

`sh` does not support globstar, unlike `bash`, so you'll need to change which shell NPM wants to use. This can be done by adding a `.npmrc` file to your project, and [setting the `script-shell` option](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#script-shell) to `bash`.